# How to execute a stored procedure SQL (MySQL) on Unix

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, stored-procedures

how to execute a stored procedure SQL (MySQL) on Unix ..?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the risk of being called facetious

```
EXECUTE stored_procedure
```

Comment: so when i m connected in my sql via shell, how to do for create my procedure ..? I have script in file .txt

Comment: use SOURCE filename. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html

Comment: @Mercer - If you want to know how to *create* a procedure, don't just ask how to *run* it.